# Android: ListView add gradient for each row

Tags: android, listview, gradient

I want to add gradient for each row. What I've tried to do is on listview label put this attribut, android:background="@drawable/mygradient". But All I get is this gradient displayed all along the list. What I want is this gradient to be displayed for each item.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you use custom listview? tried code may help to give answers, post the code

Comment: Displayed along the list..how does this look? Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a custom adapter for your list view and set the gradient as the background in its `getView` method.  Something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<MyDataType> myData;
    Context context;

    public MyAdaptor(Context ctx, List<MyDataType> myData) {
        this.myData = myData;
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    public int getCount() { return myData.size() };
    public Object getItem(int pos) { return myData.get(pos); }
    public long getItemId(int pos) { return 0L; }

    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //this is where you can customise the display of an individual
        //list item by setting its background, etc, etc.

        ...

        //and return the view for the list item at the end
        return <List item view>;
    }
}
```

Then you can set this adapter as the adapter for your list:

```
ListView myList = <initialise it here>
myList.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getContext(), listData);
```

Now whenever a list item needs to be displayed, `getView` method will be called, where you'll perform all the necessary display customisation, including setting the background.

Comment: it has taken to me 2 days, but By the end I've managed to do it. I wasn't used to custom adapter so it has been difficult. Anyway, thank's  for your help it has been very useful.

Comment: And over a year later it is still not marked as the answer =/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting background property set Selector of list, as below:

android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_background"